# How can I run Python program on cmd?

Tags: python

I've tried to run code on the cmd but it isn't working. I'm using windows7 and I changed the path from the default but I wrote the directory on the cmd. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `python <filename>` should work if you are in the directory where the script is located.

Answer (score 1):

python3 yourfilename.py

The above command can run your code, makesure you are at the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

make sure python in your system path;
set python root path to system environment variable；then you can run 'python filename.py' ex

Comment: Can't I change the whole path from one drive to another, like "C:\" to say "H:\" ?
It's because when installing Python I changed it.